# Configure Session Manager from Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I have some requests in my app to REST services that uses HTTPS, so in my AppDelegate I'd like to configure once the Session Manager from Alamofire to use the ServerTrustPolicy.

I used the code below, but I had to use the same code before each Alamofire Request, now I am refactoring my code and I'd like to know how configure the Session Manager without have to change the snipet code where I use **Alamofire.request**.

```
private static var Manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {

// Create the server trust policies
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
   "https://www.example.com": .disableEvaluation
]

// Create custom manager
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)

return manager
}()
```

**EDIT**

I tried create an extension, but did not work.

```
extension SessionManager {

    convenience init() {

        print("xxxxxx")

        let policies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["https://www.example.com.br": .disableEvaluation]

        let manager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: policies)

        self.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
                  delegate: SessionDelegate(),
                  serverTrustPolicyManager: manager)
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to avoid? the use of manager.request?

Comment: Yes. I am trying create an extension.

Comment: I will try and post any result, is an interesting question

Comment: @ReinierMelian the attempt to create an extension did not work.